# How to normalize bimodal (or multimodal) distributions?

Tags: distributions, normalization, expectation-maximization

If I have multiple data series,

a = [a1, a2, ... a100] ~ bimodal with mu_a1, mu_a2, sigma_a1, sigma_a2,

b = [b1, b2, ... b100] ~ bimodal with mu_b1, mu_b2, sigma_b1, sigma_b2,

c = [c1, c2, ... c100] ~ bimodal with mu_c1, mu_c2, sigma_c1, sigma_c2,

how do I normalize a, b, and c to follow the same distribution? Say, for the purposes of combining the data?

If a, b, and c followed a Gaussian distribution, for example, all I'd have to do is subtract the means and scale to the same standard deviation. But what about in bimodal or multimodal distributions with multiple means and standard deviations?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What is the purpose of the normalization?

Comment: @AndyW Say, customers a, b, and c are rating objects 1-100 and I want to combine each of their ratings into a single set of ratings for the 100 objects. A direct mean of the ratings of each object may not work well if each customer used the rating scale differently.